# What is the percentage of degrees at each school earned through an exclusively distance-education program?

Tags: collegescorecard

I have been trying to get at this question by looking at the percentage of degrees granted in each subject area and then examining whether the degrees offered in that subject area are offered online. The problem, however, is that the available data does not indicate what percentage of the degrees awarded are associate's degrees and what percentage are bachelor's degrees. Therefore, I am unable to determine what total percentage of degrees are earned through an exclusively distance-education program in each subject area. Does anyone have any advice on this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The number of degrees conferred for each institution disaggregated by which of those degrees were awarded to exclusively online students is not available on College Scorecard. In addition, I am not aware of any federal sources that provide these data at the institutional level.